# Populating Multiple Textboxes from Listbox Selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on an assignment for a VB / intro to programming course and I'm stumped.

Basically, the app I'm writing is a forms-based application wherein a listbox is populated with the results from a comma separated text file. The goal is to be able to sort the listbox, refine the view/results of the listbox, edit the items within the listbox, view the details of a selected item in the listbox… among other tasks. Of the items mentioned, those last two are where I'm stuck: editing/viewing the selected item.

The assignment states that selecting to "view" or "update" **the selected listbox item** requires that a new form — populated with the appropriate textboxes for each aspect of the item to be edited — be opened for viewing/updating.

Diagram:

[image]

That's where I'm stumped: getting the data for all five fields into each respective textbox **based off of the selected listbox item**... and then being able to save changes to the fields of that one row in the .txt datasource.

Here's how I currently have my listbox populated on form_load:

```
Private Sub frmInventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim books() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")
        Dim n As Integer = books.Count - 1
        ReDim book(n)
        Dim data() As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To n
            data = books(i).Split(","c)
            book(i).title = data(0)
            book(i).author = data(1)
            book(i).category = data(2)
            book(i).price = data(3)
            book(i).stock = data(4)
        Next
        Dim booksAllQuery = From col In book
                         Where col.category = "F" Or col.category = "N"
                         Select col.title
        lstBooks.DataSource = booksAllQuery.ToList
    End Sub
```

*Forgive me for the newbieness of my question, fellow stackoverflowers, as I attempt to hopefully fill in what I feel is a gap in the textbook. (And many thanks in advance!)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have all the data of the books in a database (or an array of book-objects). To edit a book you can for example overload the `.ShowDialog` method of your editor-form.

```
Public Class frmEditor
    Private WorkingRecord As Book
    Public Overloads Function ShowDialog(owner As IWin32Window, ByRef record As Book) As DialogResult
        WorkingRecord = record
        tbTitle.Text = record.Title
        tbAuthor.Text = record.Author
        ...
        Return MyBase.ShowDialog(owner)
    End Function
End Class
```

You can then call this function with the record you want to edit and it fills in the values from the record.
I added the WorkingRecord field to allow you to write the results back to the record when the user clicks save. It should work.

Another method (more in context of databindings) would be to directly bind the textbox's text properties to the Title, Author and so on properties of the book object you passed.

```
tbTitle.DataBindings.Clear()    
tbTitle.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", record, "Title"))
```

That way, the changes you do in the textboxes are directly transferred to the object you passed.
It all depends on what the final outcome should be, so take these maybe as hints.